# Sort a Perl array of objects by dates

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

I need to order the `@list` array by `insertDate`, but how can I access it since it is a `$obj` array?

I tried Perl's `sort` function but I don't understand how it works with this kind of array composed of `$obj`.

```
sub getLastQuestions {
  my ($page) = @_;
  $page ||= 1;

  my $questionPerPage = 30;
  my @list            = [];

  my @questions = $db->findNodes("/db/questions/question");

  if (@questions) {
    foreach my $question (@questions) {
      my $id         = $question->findvalue("\@id");
      my $title      = $question->findvalue("title");
      my $author     = $question->findvalue("author");
      my $insertDate = $question->findvalue("insertDate");

      my $obj = Model::Question->new(
        path       => "vedi-domanda.cgi?id=" . $id,
        title      => $title,
        author     => $author,
        insertDate => $insertDate
      );

      # Aggiungi uno
      push @list, $obj;
    }
  }

  return @list;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2939816/2088135

Comment: What is the value of `insertDate`? And how are you going to access it through `$obj`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there is no need for

```
if (@questions) { ... }
```

because

```
foreach my $question (@questions) { ... }
```

will not execute if the array is empty

There is also a bug in your initialisation of `@list`, which you are setting to `[]`. This doesn't empty the array - it sets it to have one element which contains a reference to an empty array. Just `my @list` is correct.

The easiest way to do this is to sort the `@questions` array before transforming it into an array of `Model::Question` objects.

The exact code depends entirely on the format of the date strings in the XML, but if they are well-formed, like an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date, then they can just be sorted as strings to get the desired effect. So you could write

```
  my @questions = sort {
    my ($aa, $bb) = map $_->findvalue('insertDate'), ($a, $b);
    $aa cmp $bb;
  } $db->findNodes('/db/questions/question');
```

*Please note that you haven't shown the format of your date strings, so this may not work without some additional coding*

You may also want to use `map` to convert the XML nodes into `Model::Question` objects, as I show in this subroutine

```
sub get_last_questions {

  my ($page) = @_;
  $page ||= 1;

  my $_PerPage = 30;

  my @questions = sort {
    my ($aa, $bb) = map $_->findvalue('insertDate'), ($a, $b);
    $aa cmp $bb;
  } $db->findNodes('/db/questions/question');

  my @list = map {
    Model::Question->new(
      path       => 'vedi-domanda.cgi?id=' . $_->findvalue('@id'),
      title      => $_->findvalue('title'),
      author     => $_->findvalue('author'),
      insertDate => $_->findvalue('insertDate'),
    );
  } @questions;

  return @list;
}
```

Comment: @user2458579: The central concept of Stack Overflow is that it should evolve into a library of solutions for most programming problems. If this post has helped you it would be good if you could write a comment saying something about your experience. In particular you have never described the date strings that you want to use to sort the records. Others who may find this useful would be helped if you would repay my effort by writing a description of your final solution. Thank you